# How to find part of string on website and save it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

So i wanted to make a small instagram bot for myself. I would manually open a few tabs of different instagram users (because my bot can´t do that) and search for 'sc' or "snapchat" and whats coming after that. Then i would like to save it and then i would change the tab with 'send.keys(Keys.Control + Keys.Tab) and then i would search again. But anythting i could find and figure out was how to login in. And can you run a python program in an existing tab and then search for some strings. My most knowledge is in C++, because we learn that in school.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/bin/chromedriver")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher")
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
#This is just for the login, getting to the website and finding the username
#and password field to  fillout.
```

This would be for logging in and this for clicking the button and getting to the homescreen

```
#Here i couldn´t find a method to click the button so i used the key tab to get
#on the button and then click it
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(u'\ue007')
ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").click()
#at the end i would click an automated instagram popup away
```

```
#here i would go to the searchbar and type in the wanted user
instagram = 'userxy'
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > input").send_keys(instagram)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

I couldn´t find a method that works or i could understand, but if a instagram user has their snapchat name in their biography it would save it to a file. As example i would type in 'the rock' and if he had his snapchat in his biography like 'Snapchat:therock' it would save the whole string

Comment: What exactly is your code doing here, and what are you trying to do next? I can tell you are logging in, but adding some comments above each step would help.

Comment: i just added some extra info, i hope it is now a little bit more understanding

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, this helps. I can try to help you come up with something.

Comment: yes, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem description, it sounds like you want to search on Instagram and grab results from someone's profile. I can get you started with a rough example on how to do that:

```
# locate search bar and send text to it
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search']").send_keys("userxy")

# click the first search result that pops up
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fuqBx']/a[1]"))).click()

# get the text from their instagram bio
bio = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text

# check if text contains "snapchat"
if ("snapchat" in bio):

    # split the instagram bio by newline char to get line with snapchat name
    bio_lines = bio.split("\n")

    # parse over the instagram bio to find snapchat username
    for line in bio_lines:

        # if we find the line with username, strip out text to get the username
        if ("Snapchat:" in line):
            snapchat_username = line.replace("Snapchat:", "")

            # you probably need to do something here to save to file
            print(snapchat_username)
```

This is pretty generic code, just meant to get you started. It's worth noting that it's basically impossible to write a simple method to find the snapchat username 100% of the time. Everyone formats their Instagram bio differently, maybe they denote their username by "sc: mysnapchat" instead of "Snapchat:therock".

Hopefully this code can get you started somewhere.

Comment: oh wow thanks, that's basically what i meant. i think i can get something started with this code. :D

Comment: Glad this has helped you out -- feel free to mark as accepted answer if this answer was useful for you.